# scale a video to multiple qualities and add watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

hello I have a ffmpeg command that scales a video to 2 different qualities and adds a watermark, the problem here is that the watermark is scaled along with the videos and it looks horrible

```
D:\electron\brenda\node_modules\ffmpeg-static\bin\win32\x64\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\entrada\videoplayback.mp4 -i C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\entrada\marca.png -filter_complex [0:0]scale=854:480[wm]; [wm][1:0]overlay=x=0:y=0[out] -map [out] -map 0:a -movflags faststart -preset fast -y C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\salida/480_videoplayback.mp4 -filter_complex [0:0]scale=640:360[wm]; [wm][1:0]overlay=x=0:y=0[out] -map [out] -map 0:a -movflags faststart -preset fast -y C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\salida/360_videoplayback.mp4
```

[video scaled to 360 with watermark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxaTO.png)

I want the watermark to remain in its original size and not escalate with the video, thank you for your help I've been here for hours

Comment: The watermark is NOT scaled in your command. I suspect you mean that the relative size of the watermark changes as the video size changes, is that so?

Comment: That's right, it changes relatively